# LPS25HB sensor with NUCLEO-F401RE

Tags: stm32, nucleo, stm32cubeide

I am using STM32CUBE IDE and, I've been struggling with reading data from X-Nucleo-IKS01A1 board which contains for example LPS25HB temperature and pressure sensor.

According to [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lps25hb.pdf) I have defined addresses and registers:

```
static const uint8_t LPS25HB_ADDR = 0xB9;
static const uint8_t TEMP_OUT_L = 0x2B;
static const uint8_t TEMP_OUT_H = 0x2C;
```

then I wanted to read data via I2c and convert raw data to Celsius:

```
//Read 2 consecutive registers in autoincrement mode starting from LPS25_TEMP_OUT_L
ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, LPS25HB_ADDR, TEMP_OUT_L|0x80, 1, Buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY); 
temp_c=(short int)(((unsigned short int)Buffer[1]<<8)+((unsigned short int)Buffer[0]));
//ret = HAL_OK so I think I am fine
```

but no matter what (changing sensor adress, heating up the sensor etc.) I am getting output equal to 8306 C - and I didn't move to the Sun,

I am newbie in this area and I am not sure do I have to send some data to sensor before acquisition or something? I was reading some similar topics like the one connected with HTS221 and haven't found such info.

Comment: your address is wrong it should be 0xba or 0xb8

Comment: it doesn't helped at all value's at buffer are same for all adresses buf[0] is 8 bit and buf[1] is 6 bit so i think problem is somewhere else

Comment: check the error codes. Try to debug. Do not only look for the result